# programmatically change left and top image

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I need programmatically change left and top image ,which set on canvas.

```
<Image x:Name="img1" Height="100" Width="100" Source="Assets/111.png" Margin="0" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="80"/>
```

Code like this:

```
private async void Image1()
        {
            ....
            //img1.Left=50;
            //img1.Top=80;
            img1.UpdateLayout();
        }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Canvas.SetLeft(img1, 50);
Canvas.SetTop(img1, 80);
```